# MySQL Keeps adding 2 extra rows after deleting!

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, navicat

I have this really weird problem with my MySQL table. After some time a realise that there are 2 extra rows at the end of the table. Deleting the entries in phpmyadmin just creates another 2 more of these unwanted rows with increasing `id` that is on `auto-increment`. I tried deleting with phpmyadmin and Navicat, both still causes the 2 extra rows to be created on refresh. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I did notice something weird, the last id which is a auto-incrementing primary key is 2682, but the AUTO_INCREMENT value in the options tab is 7567, is something amiss? These 2 values are the same for other tables which did not have this problem...

**UPDATE**: I exported the table into a .txt file, and notice there are empty entries with NULLS and default values and empty values from id=2683 to id=7567!!

Comment: Maybe there's a trigger?

Comment: *agree - open up the sql panel in phpmyadmin and run `SHOW TRIGGERS`

Comment: I tried that and no results were returned...

Comment: Can you show us the table structure? Go to the export tab in phpmyadmin for that table and check all the boxes under 'structure'

Comment: Let me try that.. I did notice something weird, the last `id` which is a auto-incrementing primary key is `2682`, but the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value in the options tab is `7567`, is something amiss? These 2 values are the same for other tables which did not have this problem...

Comment: If it's not a trigger, then perhaps something else is inserting those rows (Duh, right?). Do you have any scripts running from cron, or other users accessing your data?

Comment: @Sam Dufel: Sorry but I dont understand your instruction. Do you want me to export my entire table? How do I show you the structure from the export tab and checking all the boxes under structure?

Comment: Flimzy: No other users, its a server hosted on my pc for development. No scripts on cron. I restarted apache and mysql but its still the same. I have a feeling it has got to do with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value not matching the last value in the table (as stated 3 comments above)

Comment: Problem solved... posting solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running some erroneous Active Records code using Codeigniter framework before this happened. So the problem is really due to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` number being different from the last `id` in the table, and somehow having empty rows from `id=2683` to `id=7567`.

Solution was to export table to excel, delete the old table from db, remove all rows after `id=2682` in excel and import the excel back into the table to recreate the original table.

Thanks for the suggestions guys! :)